# How to simulate pinch zoom in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing a pinch zoom feature for a mobile app written in javascript and I want to test this in Google Chrome with the mobile device emulation feature. But I cannot find a way to test a pinch gesture.

I tried everything I could find on the internet (pressing Shift and moving the mouse, pressing Alt and moving the mouse), but none of this worked. Is there even a "native" way in Google Chrome to simulate a pinch zoom gesture?

btw I'm using the MacOs version of Google Chrome version 59.0.3071.86

Comment: The `Shift + Hold click down + Move mouse up / down` method works only in device emulation in dev tools, it would be great to have it in normal usage too...  :(   (Also for those who have touch pads, just use the pinching gesture as you do on your phone and it should work - it works for me -.)

Answer (score 117, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse click & drag across the viewport

Works for me. Only problem is that the `touchstart` event will return `1` for `originalEvent.touches`

Comment: Sorry, guy, I downvoted and it was an issue with the website that I was testing. You are right, and if it helps, here it is a list of other shorcuts:
http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/

Comment: This isn't working for me on Chrome 72. Has something changed?

Comment: @nnyby That's odd, it's working for me on Chrome 72 on Windows 10.

Comment: @vsync : `shift` + mouse click and drag does not work on tocuhpad of Apple Macbook Pro. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @vsync - I am not sure what you mean? Macbook is not a touch enabled device! I want to test iPad behaviour on my Macbook using Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: @maverick - Macbooks supposed to have [multi-finger trackpad gestures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895).

Comment: @vsync - Yes, but the gestures have no effect on the webpage when viewed through the Chrome Dev Tools emulator..

Comment: @maverick - Try following [this guide](https://www.frontify.com/en/blog/how-to-emulate-touch-events-in-chrome/), maybe it will solve it

Comment: @vsync: The guide seems to be for older versions of Chrome, as I can't see the options given there in the latest Chrome version.

Comment: Weird thing is this seems to zoom in even when the viewport meta tag is set to `user-scalable=no`

Comment: @catamphetamine - just tried and **it works**. You need to *make sure* you're in [device-mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode)

Comment: It does not work as the people intend to use it, the shift click emulates only the document zoom gesture. That means it wont work with custom javascript to detect a pinch zoom on, for example, a WebGL canvas or a specific DOM element or any other non-standard ways the gesture is implemented in your frontend project.

Comment: @Tom the viewport meta is supposed to work only for mobile devices (and even then, some, like safari, ignore it anyway).

Comment: The guide above is outdated - the option in chrome is now under "sensors" in the "touch" section, which can be set to "Force enabled". BUT it still does not work with the touchpad (the setting only seems to convert mouse clicks to touches - but wheel event stays the same). In short, mac users are pretty much f'ed.

Comment: That also means that this answer is not useful/current anymore....and there's basically no way of doing it without an external/touch-enabled device.

Answer (score 15):

On Chrome v.71.x.x, you can pinch zoom pressing 'Toggle Device toolbar' at dev tools and after hold SHIFT and click-drag your mouse.

Answer (score 7):

Pinch gestures have different listeners in different browsers but there is an outstanding lightweight library named [hammer.js](https://hammerjs.github.io/) which handles pinch,swipe and .... pretty easy and fine in all browsers, Unfortunately it does not support Desktop Chrome, so you can not debug your web-mobile codes easily,

Shift-Mouse click&dragging on Desktop Chrome with hammer library also does not work fine, it activates hammer's Pan event instead of pinch and works just once!, after that it keeps calling Pan event when you move your mouse through your viewport which is quite annoying and makes the debug impossible.

**Solution :**
The only convenient way, that I know, to test your gestures on a mobile browser is to use either Safari to Safari connection on ios/osx devices or Chrome to Chrome connection for android devices.

I use to debug my JavaScript codes with Chrome DevTools but in web-mobile projects I use Safari Web Inspector, because I have an iphone and a Mac!. you also can not debug your ios device with Desktop Chrome.

Take a look at this [article](https://css-tricks.com/using-chrome-devtools-to-debug-javascript-in-any-browser-with-ghostlab-2/) to find out how to setup your Safari Web Inspector.

**Note:** you need to connect your iphone to your mac using usb-cable and enable Web Inspector on your iphone (Settings-> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector) If you are unable to see **Develop** menu on your Safari, Go to Preferences and in Advanced tab check "Show develop menu in menu bar". the rest are explained in the above mentioned article.

**Update**

It is not possible to debug an ios device on a Windows Desktop Safari.

Comment: ... which sucks because you might have an auth provider allowing only localhost redirect url and not the IP of your common network (Wifi) for Mobile and PC, which is used for debugging

Comment: @Phil Can’t agree more

Answer (score 7):

Another solution to this for testing. Use the chrome phone simulator + fake a second touch at point 0,0:

```js
function handleTouchStart(e) {
    var touches=e.targetTouches;
    touches=
        [
            {
                pageX:touches[0].pageX,
                pageY:touches[0].pageY
            },
            {
                pageX:0,
                pageY:0
            }
    ]; 
    //now use the touches variable as the list of touches.

}
```

Comment: This is a nice & simple idea, especially if you're using your own libs to control the `touch[start|move|end]` || `pointer[down|move|up]` event handlers.

Plus the pseudo  point doesn't **need** to be at `0,0` either, it's trivial to setup a alternative position via some modified.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a mobile device on hand, you can connect the device to your desktop compute and use the Remote Devices feature to debug your phone on your desktop.

For Android:

1. Enable Developer Mode and USB Debugging.
2. On your desktop go to DevTools and click on More Tools > Remote Devices under the three dot menu
3. Check the Discover USB Devices option. You'll see an authorization popup on your phone. Allow it and continue.
4. Open Chrome on your phone and you should be able to inspect all the tabs on your phone. As a bonus you can use port forwarding to forward your desktop localhost to the device's localhost so if you're running a dev application on your desktop you can debug it on mobile.

For iPhones:
I'm not too familiar with the details here because I haven't been able to try it out myself but I believe you can enable it through `chrome://inspect` and Start Logging.

Source:
https://dev.to/dev0x0/using-google-chrome-console-on-any-mobile-device-9ec

Answer (score 5):

On Chrome 66, while in device simulation mode, double-click-drag up/down zooms out/in.

Comment: I like this answer for when my left hand is busy holding up my chin and can't get to the shift key. (Note that it doesn't work on some websites like nytimes.com, which seem to only support shift).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a developer answer. I've been having problems with enlarged web pages. then the page is broken. Many web pages do not support normal zoom.
[Mouse Pinch-To-Zoom](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mouse-pinch-to-zoom/pffiadlahfhoniddbipeiiohjnlongfi) can be used with the general web.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [link-only-answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Answer (score -1):

The last answer has five negative votes, but what I want to say is that the latest chrome browser(78) on Android platform does not have the function of zoom. You may have some problems with your understanding of viewport. The scale of viewport is pinchzoom. If you set it like this, your web page cannot trigger pinchzoom.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Your can set this way in your webpage

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=5, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

The other answers have already said that shortcuts for pinch zoom.