# Pinch Zoom in a web page in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am testing the rendering of my web application on iPad. However, I am not able to zoom into the page when using Chrome tools to simulate iPad under "Toggle Device Toolbar". I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456764/how-to-simulate-pinch-zoom-in-google-chrome) answer, but the solution given there doesn't work with the tocuhpad on my Apple MacBook Pro.

How can I test pinch and zoom using the touchpad on my Macbook? Notice that increasing zoom level from the dropdown in "Toggle Device Toolbar" simply makes the entire viewport bigger in size, rather than zooming into the webpage (which can be achieved in desktop mode in Chrome by simply pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

- Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> at the same time you hold down the left-button of the mouse.
- Now, a cross should appear on the dev-screen.
- Then, move it up and/or down (z-axis) to zoom in or out.

Comment: Thank you!

I'll be even more succinct and precise.

How did you transform that button?